# Ruby sum from multiple hashes with a lookup hash

Tags: ruby, indexing, hash, sum

I have the following data in 3 separate hashes:

```
produce = {100=>"apples",200=>"oranges",300=>"pears"}
north = {100=>10,200=>7,300=>11}
south = {100=>5,200=>19,300=>0}
```

I need an inventory count for all produce items in all areas as:

```
{"apples"=>15,"oranges"=>26,"pears"=>11}
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Instead of asking us to provide you with code, you should show us what you've tried and we'll help you fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
Hash[north.merge(south){ |_, a, b| a + b}.map{ |k,v| [produce[k], v]}]
```

`Hash#merge` merges two hashes.

In case of conflict when both hashes have the same key, and we pass a block, then the block is called with the key, value from one hash, value from the other hash and the result is stored as the value. Thus

```
north.merge(south) {|_, a, b| a + b}
```

does the summing part:

```
north.merge(south) {|_, a, b| a + b}
#=> {100=>15, 200=>26, 300=>11}
```

Next we use `map` to transform the key of the sum hash:

```
north.merge(south) {|_, a, b| a + b}.map{ |k,v| [produce[k], v]}
#=> [["apples", 15], ["oranges", 26], ["pears", 11]]
```

And since this results in an array we use `Hash.[]` to convert it back into a hash:

```
Hash[north.merge(south){ |_, a, b| a + b}.map{ |k,v| [produce[k], v]}]
=> {"apples"=>15, "oranges"=>26, "pears"=>11}
```

Comment: For Ruby v2+ you can use `to_h` instead of wrapping the code in `Hash[...]`.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two ways of doing that.

**#1**

```
produce.each_with_object({}) do |(k,v),h|
  h[v] = north[k].to_i + south[k].to_i
end
  #=> {"apples"=>15, "oranges"=>26, "pears"=>11}
```

**#2**

```
h = produce.invert
  #=> {"apples"=>100, "oranges"=>200, "pears"=>300} 
h.keys.each { |k| h[k] = north[h[k]].to_i + south[h[k]].to_i }
h
  #=> {"apples"=>15, "oranges"=>26, "pears"=>11}
```

I've appended `to_i` in the event that `north` or `south` does not have a key `h[k]`, as `nil.to_i #=> 0`.

Note that the values of `produce` must be unique for you to obtain your desired result.